# spring batch: process large file

Tags: jms, datasource, spring-batch

I have 10 large files in production, and we need to read each line from the file and convert comma separated values into some value object and send it to JMS queue and also insert into 3 different table in the database

if we take 10 files we will have 33 million lines. We are using spring batch(MultiResourceItemReader) to read the earch line and have write to write it o db and also send it to JMS. it roughly takes 25 hrs to completed all.

Eventhough we have 10 system in production, presently we use only one system to run this job( i am new to spring batch, and not aware how spring supports in load balancing)

Since we have only one system we configured data source to connect to db and max connection is specified as 25.

To improve the performance we thought to use spring multi thread support. started to use 5 threads. we could see the performance improvement and could see everything completed in 10 hours.

Here i Have below questions:
1) if i process using 5 threads, we will publish huge amount of data into JMS queue. Will queue support huge data.Note we have 10 systems in production to read JMS Message from the queue. 
2) Using thread(5) and 1 production system is good approach (or) instead of spring batch insert the data into db i can create a rest service and spring batch calls the rest api to insert the data into db and let spring api inserts data into JmS queue(again, if spring batch process file annd use rest to insert data into db, per second i will read 4 or 5 lines and will call the rest api. Note we have 10 production system). If use rest API approach will my system support(rest can handle huge request using load balancer, and also JMS can handle huge and huge message) or using thread in spring batch app using 1 production system is better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Different JMS providers are going to have different limits, but in general messaging can easily handle millions of rows in a small period of time.

Messaging is going to be faster than inserting directly into the database because a message has very little data to manage (other than JMS properties) instead of the overhead of a complete RDBMS or NoSQL database or whatever, messaging out performs them all.

Assuming the individual lines can be processed in any order, then sending all data to the same queue and have n consumers working the back-end is a sound solution.

Your big bottleneck, however, is getting the data into the database.  If the destination table(s) have m/any keys/indices on them, there is going to be serious contention because each insert/update/delete needs to rebuild the indices, so even though you have n different consumers trying to update the database, they're going to trounce on each other as the transactions are completed.

One solution I've seen is disabling all database constrains before you start and enabling at the end, and hopefully if things worked the data is consistent and usable; of course, the risk is there was bad data that you didn't catch and now you need to clean up or reattempt the load

A better solution might be to transform the files into a single file that can be batch loaded into the database using a platform-specific tool.  These tools often disable indexes, contraint checking, and anything else that's going to slow things down - often times bypassing SQL itself - to get performance.